# Java : Is it possible to set paramters selectively?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Using jdk1.8. I need to set a param in a jpa-native-query based on a boolean value. Something like **(Please see the part where based on "addEmail"'s  true/false value , trying to set/ignore "param3". em is the entityManager)**:

```
results = em.createNativeQuery(executionQuery)
                .setParameter("param1", val1)
                .setParameter("param2", val2)
                 if (addEmail){ .setParameter("param3", val3)}
                .setFirstResult(offset)
                .setMaxResults(max)
                .getResultList();
```

is there  a way to do that? I was looking for some QueryOption. Not finding a good example

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to do all that method concatenation and get the resultset directly? And is there a reason why you can't set `companyIdsOnBehalf` to a value that would have the same effect as not setting it (i. e. so that part of the where clause ends up as `companyIdsOnBehalf like '%'`). Because if there isn't, you can set `param1` and `param2`, then set `companyIdsOnBehalf` to whichever value depending on the `addEmail` flag, then do the calls to `.setFirstResult()` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't this work for you?

```
var executionQuery = addEmail ? queryWithEmail : queryNoEmail;

var query = em.createNativeQuery(executionQuery)
                .setParameter("param1", val1)
                .setParameter("param2", val2)
                .setFirstResult(offset)
                .setMaxResults(max);

if (addEmail) query.setParameter("param3", val3);
   
return query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Am I missing something or you should also update the query? You cannot just add a parameter on its own.

Comment: I thought the question was related to how it can be done in "pure" Java :D but yeah, if the query requires that parameter the question does not even make sense.

Comment: @VictorGram you need to do what I show above, but also use a different "executionQuery" ofc.

Comment: Edited the answer with the obvious change in query depending on the parameter being added or not.